# how to test to see if an element exists in DOM in Jasmine Jquery

Tags: jasmine, automated-tests

I need to write a unit a test to see if a DOM element exists using Jquery jasmine. I have used standalone jasmine and included Jquery Jasmine and Jquery CDNs into my SpecRunner.html

Comment: You can share a piece of code, community members will be happy helping you. If you are new to jquery jasmine you can search for the good article and come up with a small implementation of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look into jasmine-jquery GitHub page you'll find toBeInDOM() matcher which checks that. here is an example of code that you need to include in your spec folder. just remeber that it is important to get the path to HTML right. look for console logs for any possible issue with path to your fixture.

```js
    describe("Dom element Test", function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            loadFixtures('path/to/your/fixture.html');
        });

        it("should be in HTML page", function () {
            expect($('#ID-of-your-html-elemnt')[0]).toBeInDOM()
        });

    });
```

Comment: I need to dynamically generate items in my HTML page instead of Fixture. is it possible?

Comment: you can include a JS script to create HTML elements dynamically and then append it using a parent method (lets call it setUpHTMLFixture()) and then add setFixtures() method. then call the parent method using setUpHTMLFixture(); in your Spec